# VSCode Debug Console only shows nodemon messages

Tags: node.js, nodemon, vscode-debugger

I added launch config to run a small app for testing purposes like so

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "restart": true,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\express-qr-code.js"
        }
    ]
```

But when I get an error it doesn't log the error in console and shows only the nodemon output. e.g.:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect .\express-qr-code.js`
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So as you can tell its very counterproductive for debugging.

This is what I get when starting the same app from the terminal

```
PS C:\Projects\Testing\Node> nodemon .\express-qr-code.js
[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .\express-qr-code.js`
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1306:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1442:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Projects\Testing\Node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Testing\Node\express-qr-code.js:162:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1333:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can I make debug console show all the messages?

Comment: It's because you are now debugging nodemon instead of your app. Change it to run your app with node, not nodemon.

Comment: But by doing that I lose the ability to restart on file changes. Isn't there a way to debug the node app while launching it with nodemon?

Answer (score 0):

It seems could not find a way to launch the nodemon process and inspect the launch file. The only solution was to have the logs be shown in the terminal window while the debugging logs get shown in the debug console. The repo has a readme [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon) where the go through achieving the setup. You will get all the logs just in the terminal window. Just without the debug console message. Those will be in the debug console